# HTML 5 postMessage (same domain)

Tags: html, postmessage

I am trying to get the HTML postMessage function working?

I have a found a few sites giving the example but for some reason a struggling.

The code for the 2 pages is shown below, any help would be apprecaited.

Thanks and Regards,
Ryan

**test.php**

```
<iframe src="postmessage-target.html" id="iframe"></iframe>
 <form id="form">
   <input type="text" id="msg" value="Message to send"/>
   <input type="submit"/>
 </form>
 <script>
 window.onload = function(){
         var win = document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow;
         document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function(e){
                 win.postMessage( document.getElementById("msg").value );
                 e.preventDefault();
         };
 };
 </script>
```

**postmessage-target.html**

```
<div id="test">Send me a message!</div>
 <script>
 document.addEventListener("message", function(e){
         document.getElementById("test").textContent =
                 e.domain + " said: " + e.data;
 }, false);
 </script>
```

Thanks again in advance.

Ryan

**UPDATE**

Is this correct as per user advice?

**test.html**

```
<iframe src="postmessage-target.html" id="iframe"></iframe>
 <form id="form">
   <input type="text" id="msg" value="Message to send"/>
   <input type="submit"/>
 </form>
 <script>
 window.onload = function(){
         var win = document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow;
         document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function(e){
                 win.postMessage( document.getElementById("msg").value, "*"); 
                 e.preventDefault();
         };
 };
 </script>
```

**postmessage-target.html**

```
<div id="test">Send me a message!</div>
 <script>
 document.addEventListener("message", function(e){
 document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = e.origin + " said: " + e.data;
 }, false);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The norm specifies that you should provide the targetOrigin to the postMessage function :

```
 win.postMessage( document.getElementById("msg").value, "*");
```

I don't think there is a `e.domain`. Try `e.origin` in the listener :

```
 document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = e.origin + " said: " + e.data;
```

(I also replaced the non standard textContent by innerHTML)

Comment: Hi @dystroy, please see update, have I done this correctly? Thanks,

Comment: I still see the same errors. Are you sure you updated ? BTW the best is to try.

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work, I ended up having to change document.addEventListener to window.addEventListener- I think you're adding the receiving code to the transmitting document instead of the iframe when you do it that way.